# Cannot use Conditional Formatting in Workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting, microsoft-excel-2016

The problem is simple enough to state. When I select a range of cells (as numeric values or indeed as values calculated from a formula), I cannot conditionally format them. What I want to do is to colorize numbers highest (red) to lowest (blue). I have done this before a million times by using:

1. On Home tab Conditional Formatting > New Rule.
2. In the New Formatting Rule dialog box, "Format all cells based on their value".
3. Set color scale.
4. Ok.

Simple. But this just does nothing now. Is there a setting I am missing or may have accidentally changed? I have tried Shift + F9 to recalculate the range - NOTHING.

I am a broken man.

Comment: You might have already a rule that goes first, and if it is true, your new one is never even considered. Use 'maintain rules' to get an overview.

Comment: I have cleared all rules from the entire workbook. This should prevent what you suggest shouldn't it? Where is"Maintain Rules"?

Comment: Yes it should. - I am not at a computer, so I don't have the exact look and wording in the menu, but the 'conditional' button should have a mini-dropdown with four options, and one is 'maintain' or so.

Comment: You can use directly after selecting the Data, Conditional Formatting, Color Scales it will color, or in your case if you choose 2-color scales choose Blue for lowest and Red for highest, maybe you did not set both in all cases you can Manage rules to see what you set

Comment: Yeah, but this is just not working at all. I am wondering if I have turned something off accidentally?

Comment: Maybe the Data is not numbers or Excel does not recognize it as number show some data

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem and none of the solutions here was the answer, but it was a very simple issue.

If you have selected various Sheets in your Excel file (like a Shift + Click), it stays selected until you click another sheet, **and having various sheets selected** makes the **Conditional Formatting Grayed Out** 
*(also many other options as well)*

Just click any other sheet and it deselects all others.

Answer (score 1):

The source data was in text format, that is why I couldn't remove the thousand separators by changing the format. It seems that any time that you try to change formatting on numbers and it doesn't work that will be the reason why.

If you go to the offending sheet, then select a single offending cell (double click to enter edit mode) and move the cursor within the text, you will see that there are hidden spaces before the first digit, and possibly  one after, whenever this happens, the data is text, and is formatted as such, even when it looks like a number.

The spaces in my sheet were not normal spaces, they were brought in from a web source, but can be removed easily.

1. Go to the relevent sheet, and make sure that you only have a single cell selected.
2. Check that Num Lock on your computer is on (you need to use the number pad).
3. Press Ctrl h to open the find and replace dialogue box.
4. Click into the Find box, then hold down the Alt key, and type 0160 on the number pad (using the number keys along the top of the keyboard will not work).
5. Release the Alt key.
6. Click into the Replace box and check that it is empty.
7. Click Replace All.

That should have now cleared all of the stray characters from your data source and allow you to format numbers correctly.